# How do I get the Sun Java 6 package on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, java

I have Ubuntu. I want to install the Sun JDK version 6 using the command line (apt-get). How do I do that. What is the name of the package?

Or is the open JDK version the only option.

Comment: Don't use OpenJDK at the moment for Swing applications. It will result in truncated controls, paint problems or other mysterious bugs.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming it's Ubuntu 10.04,

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner"
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can install by apt-get:

```
apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-jdk
```

Comment: Ramesh ... I get this output. Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package sun-java6-jdk is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package sun-java6-jdk has no installation candidate